# AngularJS - project files layout, injection and scope clarification

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking at some of the patterns in use for setting up new projects, I'm trying to understand what seems to be a common pattern for scaffolding larger Angular projects.

If you look at the structure below, in each file there is a variable declared with the angular.module container to add controllers, directives etc., which are injected into the app (myApp) in the app.js file as dependencies.

While I'm seeing very simple examples of this pattern, I'm unsure of whether it scales the way I've assumed it does here, or if I'm missing something entirely and this isn't the correct way to scaffold a larger project.

For example, if I create a separate (second) file for specific controllers, and load it after my current controllers.js file, can I just start with "myControllers.controller('MyController..." to define the additional controllers, or do I need to create a new variable, assign angular.module, inject it into the app etc. and add controllers to that new variable in the second file?

Does the first way (if that's valid) mean that all my controllers have access to each others public variables and methods, and the latter isolates each file's controllers from the other and require that I communicate through services?

Should I be simply declaring one var myApp - angular.module('myApp',[]); in the app.js file and then referencing myApp.controller, myApp.filter, myApp.factory in all the other files directly without creating new specific variables for each type?

I feel like I'm missing some core piece of insight that would make all of these answers clear, but I don't have it at present.

I know there are preferences as to creating folders for each functional block, each with its own controller, services etc. files, and I'm not interested in that, I want to understand this structure correctly.

Thanks,
:Steve

---

file: app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
]);
```

file: controllers.js

```
var myControllers = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);

myControllers.controller('MyController', function MyController ($scope, $http...)
```

file: directives.js

```
var myDirectives = angular.module('myApp.directives', []);

myDirectives.directive('MyDirective', function MyDirective ($scope, $http...)
```

file: filters.js

```
var myFilters = angular.module('myApp.filters', []);

myFilters.filter('MyFilter', function MyFilter ($scope, $http...)
```

file: services.js

```
var myServices = angular.module('myApp.services', []);

myServices.service('MyService', function MyService ($scope, $http...)
or
myServices.factory('MyFactory', function MyFactory ($scope, $http...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this structure does fall within [Google's style guidelines](https://google.github.io/styleguide/angularjs-google-style.html), most smaller applications won't call for this type of strictness, especially in the prototyping phase. As a result, hanging your services, directives and factories off of `app` should be fine.

> Should I be simply declaring one var myApp -
>   angular.module('myApp',[]); in the app.js file and then referencing
>   myApp.controller, myApp.filter, myApp.factory in all the other files
>   directly without creating new specific variables for each type?

As noted above, I'd wager that the general answer here would be "yes." And the only time one would need to modify the `angular.module('myApp', ['someThirdPartyModule'])` declaration would be for third-party libraries.

**But...**

There are drawbacks to not initially building your services, factories, directives, etc., as reusable components and then injecting them into your application - mainly, you obviously lose the ability to have a reusable component :-)

For instance, let's say you now have to support two modules:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myOtherApp', []);
```

If we don't have injectable services at this point, they need to be built for each instance of `myApp` and `myOtherApp`, which wouldn't be ideal if they both need to, say, fetch data from a server. If that were the scenario, why not build a generic `DataAccessService` that can be injected at the highest level into both modules?

So to close the loop, the only benefit I see is the ability to gain reusability across multiple unrelated applications. It seems filters (i.e. formatters), data services and generic directives could be done at this level, but for components that only make sense for `myApp` and `myOtherApp` respectively, it would seem those services would be attached to just that application. For instance, `myApp` has an `OrdersService`, and `myOtherApp` has `CustomerService`, but both utilize `DataAccessService` which was injected at the application level.

Comment: Thanks @lux! There's lots of example of different layouts, but no explanation of why they're different at this level. Even the people with a strong preference one way or the other don't explain why clearly.

Comment: No problem, I've had the same experience, lots of practicality with no explanations! Also, I updated my answer to be a bit less subjective, and I did mention that reusability might just be the ticket overall.